# Finding an Angle between two lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, angle

I have 2 lines with coordinates A(x1,y1; x2,y2) and B (x3,y3; x4,y4). Can I find the angle between them using MatLab.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use some kind of graphical interface? Or do you just want to solve it by programming in the math?

Comment: just solve... I have 30 like this figures in one plate. I want to calculate each of them. i have matrix with values of x1,x2..y3,y4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess if you are just looking for the code, something like this should do?

```
v1=[x2,y2]-[x1,y1];
v2=[x4,y4]-[x3,y3];
angle=acos(sum(v1.*v2)/(norm(v1)*norm(v2)));
```

Comment: I think code works,, but x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4 each of them have 30 values. your code gives just 2 values. v1 and v2 also have values <30x2 double>. How to change, so that "angle" gave me 30 values.   I have 30 like this figures in one plate. i have matrix with values of x1,x2..y3,y4.

Comment: but you need to make your question make more sense, you have 30 values - so you mean your line is described by 30 value pairs? If so just pick any 2, since any 2 points creates a line, 30 is redundant.