# Get angle between two lines of a time series in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series, angle

How can I calculate angle in degrees between lines AB and BC in Matlab?

[Time-series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luSjq.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding an Angle between two lines in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589661/finding-an-angle-between-two-lines-in-matlab)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067083/find-the-angle-between-two-given-lines-2d and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461268/calculate-angle-between-two-vectors-matlab -- all variations on the same theme. Any of these solves your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit of an unusual request, but the code below should do the trick :).

```
% X and Y coordinates of your time series
X = (1:9)';
Y = [-3;-1;-1.2;-4.5;-5.5;.2;-2;-.5;-.4];

angle_rad = zeros(size(X,1)-2,1);         % Preallocate the angle vector
for i = 1:(size(Y,1)-2)                 % Loop over all vector pairs

    % Vectors:
    a = [X(i+1)-X(i);Y(i+1)-Y(i)];      % first vector
    b = [X(i+2)-X(i+1);Y(i+2)-Y(i+1)];  % second vector

    % Vector properties:
    dot_prod = a'*b;
    l_a = norm(a);                      % length of first vector
    l_b = norm(b);                      % length of second vector

    % Angle:
    angle_rad(i) = pi - acos(dot_prod/(l_a*l_b));  % [rad]
end
angle_deg = angle_rad.*180./pi; % [degrees]
```

See if this works, but this code is a little clumsy, maybe if we knew what you were using this for, there could be a better option?